# Is there is any hook like "didInsertElement" in router?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Using third party framework, I want set selected value.

Is there is any hook after view inserted into DOM in ember.js new router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with Karl above. However, maybe you've just asked the question in a bad way. In the new router, you have the `setupController`, which is invoked when Ember moves into that route. So for example, if you move into `/#/dashboard`, then `DashboardController`, `DashboardView`, `DashboardRoute` will all be initialised.

Aside from the fact that you could use the `didInsertElement` on the `DashboardView` at this point, you have the `setupController` method which you can overwrite in the `DashboardRoute`. In here you can set-up the controller, and perhaps do whatever it is you're trying to do:

*(The `setupController` will only be invoked when you enter the route, but the view won't have rendered by the time you're moving into it. For that you'll need `didInsertElement` and that's that. `setupController` is for setting up the controller, which can be thought of as an ever-persistent singleton.)*

```
var DashboardRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        // We're in the route, so let's do something now.
        controller.set('myText', 'Add this to the controller!');
    }
});
```